# How to define Lightning CSS based on resolution?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to hide/show iteration header based on screen resolution. Need the header to be hidden at low resolutions.

I'm not sure if my approach is right.

**Markup**

```
<div class="hideinlowres">
     header text!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS { 

    .hideinlowres{
      display: block ;
      @media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
        display: none;
      }
    }
}
```

This has a parser error. What would be the correct way to hide the Lightning component div based on resolution.

Appreciate any help on this. 
Thanks.

Comment: First, it should be .THIS .ClassName{ } and secondly, follow the above link for possible resolution for media query. If you are still not getting anywhere, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to add CSS with media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  .THIS .hideinlowres{
      display: none;
  }
```

}

Default CSS rule:

```
.THIS .hideinlowres{
  display: block;
}
```